# What is a proper representation of cubic, quartic and any other forms just like the matrix representation of a quadratic form?

Tags: geometry, polynomials

Given a [homogeneous polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial), when the order is 2, it is a quadratic form and we have a matrix representation, such as

$$
\begin{pmatrix}x & y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\b & c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = a x^2 + 2 b xy + c y^2
$$

So can we give tensor representations of cubic, quartic or any other forms? If tensor is not proper, which representations can cope with coordinate transformations?

Background: we know slopeness is the 1st order, and curvature is the 2nd order, and we are discussing the topics, such as how about cubic? and is roughness the 4th order?

Comment: What you are looking for is *n*-dimensinal [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor).

Comment: Thanks, @emacsdrivesmenuts , and I am checking the wiki link. For a (m, n)-tensor,  it looks m encode the polynomial order and n encode the space dimension?